# how to parse a date into clj-time by ignoring the time and secs

Tags: clojure

Given the following string, I would like to get a date-time with only the date -

String `"2013-02-20T17:24:33Z"`, I would like to get a date while ignoring the time and secs.

The following would work - `(parse (formatters :date-time-no-ms) "2013-02-2T17:24:33Z")`. However the resulting date-time object also contains the secs, how do I trim it down to just year-month-day ?

One way is do a regex and extract the required details and then parse it into a date -
`(clojure.core/re-find #"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{1,2}" "2013-02-20T17:24:33Z")`
`(parse (formatters :date) "2013-02-20")`

However there should be a better way to the above by just using clj-time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(defn floor [dt f] 
  (apply date-time 
    (map #(%1 dt) 
      (take-while (partial not= f) [year month day hour minute sec milli]))))

(floor (parse (formatters :date-time-no-ms) "2013-02-2T17:24:33Z") hour)
```

Comment: +1 for this one. The above is a very clever way of using the functional features !

Comment: @murtaza52, note, however, that this is just a hack. You shouldn't invent a way to do something if it is already present in the library.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev appreciate the advice

Answer (score 4):

`clj-time` is just a wrapper around Joda Time, so you can call methods on `DateTime` object directly, and fortunately there is a method `DateTime#toDateMidnight()`:

```
user=> (parse (formatters :date-time-no-ms) "2013-02-2T17:24:33Z")
#<DateTime 2013-02-02T17:24:33.000Z>
user=> (.toDateMidnight (parse (formatters :date-time-no-ms) "2013-02-2T17:24:33Z"))
#<DateMidnight 2013-02-02T00:00:00.000Z>
```

Comment: Vladimir Thanks for the above method ! I also have to floor the date to the month and year. Is there a method for that too ?

Comment: Yes, there is: `(-> your-date-time .dayOfMonth .withMinimumValue)` - for rounding down to the first day of current month, `(-> your-date-time .monthOfYear .withMinimumValue)` - for rounding down the the first month of current year. Official Joda Time site (http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) is great at describing these features, as well as its Javadoc (http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/overview-summary.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use the `DateTime` method `.withTimeAtStartOfDay`:

```
(let [^DateTime dt (parse (formatters :date-time-no-ms) "2013-02-2T17:24:33Z")]
  (.withTimeAtStartOfDay dt))
```

Note that the [type hint](https://clojure.org/reference/java_interop#typehints) `^DateTime` increases the performance significantly.